# Unity3D Agora video chat with Ar Foundation Face Tracking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, agora.io

I'm trying make an video chat with Agora and use AR Foundation for Face Tracking effects.

The problem is AR Foundation works with self AR Camera that overlays the Agora camera.

It's possible work with Agora camera as AR Camera for Ar Foundation? I think maybe i can replace the AR Camera from AR Foundation and set it the scripts to Agora camera, but i couldn't found the Agora Camera in scene.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by using RenderTexture to show the AR camera image and send the raw video data over using Agora's APIs.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/video-chat-with-unity3d-ar-foundation-pt3-remote-assistance-app/). As a 3rd part of a series, you may find the other two tutorials on this topic in its beginning overview too.

You may not want to build your project using the exact code from this tutorial.  But it will help you understand the concept.